# Android. Confusion whether to use broadcast receiver or service for recieving sms

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have this app which receives message every 2 mins and updates database, while other activities are running seamlessly, what should be the perfect way? Should i use a service to receive messages or just a simple activity can be used? Also, please provide a link to some sample or tutorial for the same.

Comment: Here you go a nice tutorial http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcast receiver. Since a service will keep running even when there are no messages received. While a broadcast receiver will listen to only the intent you have registered to it.

Here is link about how to use a broadcast receiver http://androidword.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver.html